# vim-rails: No such file or directory when doing Rserver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, vim

Can't find anything about this in Google.
Trying to get most out of `vim-rails`.

https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails

It has many interesting commands, like `:Rserver`, `:Rgenerate`, `:Rdestroy`, but they do not work on my machine. All they give same error:

`No such file or directory`

I would imagine it has something to do with paths, and RVM loading, but not sure what exactly.
Running on latest Lubuntu if that matters. Sometimes need to do `/bin/bash --login` to run rake.

--
Found somewhere that in `~/.profile` I should put this:

```
# PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM
```

Still same error.

--
Yes, vim-rails - is a plugin for vim that I'm trying to use.

-- Tried to run `!/bin/bash --login` from VIM - but it closes VIm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to execute these commands in the normal way?
like `rails server`, `rails generate`..

From your description, mostly because vim-rails can't find ruby or rails command to execute.

You should check the $PATH variable to see whether it has ruby or rails load path in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open vim in your working directory?

For example, if your app is in `~/workspace/my_project/`, then you should open vim in that directory:

```
cd ~/workspace/my_project
vim
```

Then the vim-rails should work as expected.

Comment: can you check if a simple command such as `:Emodel <model_name>` works?

Comment: Try to add your path of RVM in .bash_profile or .zhenv depending on your shell. eg # PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM